# I thought you were only allowed 20 suggested edit reviews/day?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits

So is this just a counting bug or what? Or am I the only person who sees this :O

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normally, yes. But if you've already used up all your reviews in that queue for the day and you happen to get a [suggested edit on your own post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5404639), the limit is ignored since you are *always* allowed to review suggested edits to your own post.